# NumPy - Efficient conversion from tuple to array?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, tuples

I'm trying to find an efficient way to convert from a tuple (where every 4 entries correspond to R, G, B, alpha of a pixel) to a NumPy array (for use in OpenCV).

More specifically, I'm using pywin32 to get the client area bitmap of a window. This is returned in the form of a tuple where the first four elements belong to the RGB-alpha channels of the first pixel, then the next four of the second pixel, and so on. The tuple itself only contains the integer data (i.e. it does not contain any dimensionality, although, I do have that information). From this tuple I want to create NumPy 3D array (width x height x channel). Currently, I'm simply creating an array of zeros, then walking through every entry in the tuple and putting it in place in the NumPy array. I'm doing this using the code below. And I'm hoping that there may be a significantly more efficient way to do this that I'm just not thinking of. Any suggestions? Thank you much!

**Code:**

```
bitmapBits = dataBitmap.GetBitmapBits(False) #Gets the tuple.
clientImage = numpy.zeros((height, width, 4), numpy.uint8)
iter_channel = 0
iter_x = 0
iter_y = 0
for bit in bitmapBits:
    clientImage[iter_y, iter_x, iter_channel] = bit
    iter_channel += 1
    if iter_channel == 4:
        iter_channel = 0
        iter_x += 1
    if iter_x == width:
        iter_x = 0
        iter_y += 1
    if iter_y == height:
        iter_y = 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to Bill above, but likely even faster:

```
clientImage = np.asarray(bitmapBits, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(height, width, 4)
```

`array` takes, according to the docs: "An array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose `__array__` method returns an array, or any (nested) sequence."

`asarray` takes a few more things: "Input data, in any form that can be converted to an array. This includes lists, lists of tuples, tuples, tuples of tuples, tuples of lists and ndarrays."  It takes tuples directly :)

Comment: This is indeed slightly faster (for my current use it's about 10% faster then the solution proposed by Bill).

Answer (score 5):

Why not just do something like

```
import numpy as np
clientImage = np.array(list(bitmapBits), np.uint8).reshape(height, width, 4)
```

For example, let `('Ri', 'Gi', 'Bi', 'ai')` be the color tuple corresponding to pixel `i`.  If you have a large tuple of these, you can do:

```
In [9]: x = ['R1', 'G1', 'B1', 'a1', 'R2', 'G2', 'B2', 'a2', 'R3', 'G3', 'B3', 'a3', 'R4', 'G4', 'B4', 'a4']

In [10]: np.array(x).reshape(2, 2, 4)
Out[10]: 
array([[['R1', 'G1', 'B1', 'a1'],
        ['R2', 'G2', 'B2', 'a2']],

       [['R3', 'G3', 'B3', 'a3'],
        ['R4', 'G4', 'B4', 'a4']]], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

Each slice `[:,:,i]` for `i in [0,4)` will give you each channel:

```
In [15]: np.array(x).reshape(2, 2, 4)[:,:,0]
Out[15]: 
array([['R1', 'R2'],
       ['R3', 'R4']], 
      dtype='|S2')
```